# Unable to overwrite existing excel sheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to format excel sheets using if else condition but unable to rewrite the file. Code is written below.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

sheet_name = "C:\\python\\book.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(sheet_name)
sheet = wb['Data1']

for row in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    print(row)
    value1 = sheet.cell(row, 1).value
    if "st1" in value1:
        value1 = "Invite"
    elif "st2" in value1:
        value1 = "Closed"  
    elif "st3" in value1:
        value1 = "Pending"  
    print(value1)
    wb.save(sheet_name)
```

Output

```
Closed
Invite
Closed
Pending
```

It does print the output which I wanted but it doesn't rewrite the excel file. File remains unchanged. How can save the file after making all the correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is missing the part where you write your output to the cell in Excel file:

```
sheet.cell(row, 1).value = value1
```

Also I would put the wb.save outside of the for loop.